# Merging 3 CSV files using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

- CSV1 Fields :`EmplID,identity,Name,PreferredName,Location,Department`
- CSV2 Fields :`identity,EmplID,first_name,last_name,email`
- CSV3 Fields :`Emplid,Extension`

I would like to merge all these 3 CSV's by comparing the value of `EmpID` which is common to all the files and generate a new CSV with all the below fields..

`EmplID,identity,Name,PreferredName,Location,Department,first_name,last_name,email,Extension`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion matt, I am sorry that i didn't mention my requirement correctly earlier..
The Output should contain entire data of CSV1 and if matches found from CSV2 and CSV3 it should add to respective column .. how can i do that.. If possible please explain me the steps too..

Answer (score 0):

It's late, and I'm bored, so let's do this...

```
$CSV1 = Import-CSV C:\Path\To\File1.csv
$CSV2 = Import-CSV C:\Path\To\File2.csv
$CSV3 = Import-CSV C:\Path\To\File3.csv

$Merged = ForEach($Record in $CSV1){
    Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName 'first_name' -NotePropertyValue ($CSV2|Where{$_.EmplID -eq $Record.EmplID}|Select -Expand first_name)
    Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName 'last_name' -NotePropertyValue ($CSV2|Where{$_.EmplID -eq $Record.EmplID}|Select -Expand last_name)
    Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName 'email' -NotePropertyValue ($CSV2|Where{$_.EmplID -eq $Record.EmplID}|Select -Expand email)
    Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName 'Extension' -NotePropertyValue ($CSV3|Where{$_.EmplID -eq $Record.EmplID}|Select -Expand Extension) -PassThru
}
$Merged | Export-CSV C:\Path\To\New.CSV -NoTypeInfo
```

That loads each CSV file into a variable, then loops through CSV1, and for each record in it 4 properties are added. For each property it attempts to find a matching record in CSV2 or CSV3 based on EmplID being the index, and expands the relative property from that record as the value of the new property. It uses the -PassThru switch for the last Add-Member so that it outputs the record once for each record, and that's all collected in the $Merged array. Then I output $Merged into a new CSV file.

Comment: Thanks TheMadTechnician, Your script works well, but the search takes a long time to complete.. for 5000 Rows it need almost 20-25 minutes...:(